# Time for us to let go of [mergeddictionaries]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

I recently saw a tag [mergeddictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mergeddictionaries).

0 watchers, 53 questions, no wiki

1. **Is it ambiguous?**:

   Yes, it should be
2. **Is there other ways to represent this tag?**:

   Of course, with [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge), and [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary), yup
3. **Does is add any useful information to the post?**:

   Not really, it can be just [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary), that's enough.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**:

   Yeah, it does

After all, I think they should be all re-tagged to [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge) and [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary), and all would be fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because the responses to the "burninate checklist" questions are bare statements of opinion without any reasoning to back them up. As such, there's no constructive discussion to be had here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell huh?, while I also dislike burniation requests, since there is a lot of work to be done, when people finished upvpting them, I'm not sure we can just close'em and look the other way. Instead vote on post as you see fit.

Comment: My point is that this isn't a _valid_ burnination post, @PetterFriberg: it's like a feature request that says "The page header should obviously be purple!" with no justification or a bug report that claims "When I clicked the 'ask question' button I was logged out" without any other details.

Comment: Meeh it's clear which tag it is, there is a minimum of reasoning and the answer is clear, I think there's no need to close it

Comment: @JoshCaswell that's a reason to downvote, not close. The request is clear - burninate [mergeddictionaries]. If you think that is not a good idea, downvote the question. If you think it is a good idea but needs to be better justified, *post an answer explaining the reasons it should be burninated*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I disagree with the burnination.

MergedDictionaries is a concept in WPF. You can read more about [it in the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/merged-resource-dictionaries).

Most of the questions are related to WPF. 31/ 53 [are already tagged with the wpf tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mergeddictionaries+wpf). Apart from these, many that are not tagged with [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) are also about the WPF MergedDictionaries. An example can be seen here [Using MergedDictionaries in generic.xaml in Silverlight 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689044/using-mergeddictionaries-in-generic-xaml-in-silverlight-3).

The wrongly tagged ones [look like they are mostly from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmergeddictionaries%5D+%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0), those just need to be retagged with [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary), and we will be done with cleaning the tag. It needs a valid tag wiki excerpt pointing to its correct usage, after which we will be done taking care of the tag. There is no need for a burnination here.

Comment: I took care of the Python ones.

Comment: Thanks, and I added a small excerpt. We can call it done now.